# Using watchers in VueJS?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js, watch

I am trying to use Watchers in VueJS but having bit of a hard time wrapping my head around them. For example in this case i have set up a `watch` which checks for the tab i am on and if the tab changes it should reset the `selected` value back to an empty array. Now i have set the parameters as `oldValue` and `newValue` but i am not quite sure how will i use those.

Check this [codepen](https://codepen.io/treehuggerrick/pen/eYpezgR?editors=1011).

Here is the Complete example:-

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      tabs: ["Tab1", "Tab2"],
      activeTab: 0,
      headers: [{
          text: "Dessert (100g serving)",
          align: "left",
          value: "name"
        },
        {
          text: "Calories",
          value: "calories"
        }
      ],
      items: [{
          name: "Ice cream sandwich",
          calories: 237
        },
        {
          name: "Frozen Yogurt",
          calories: 159
        }
      ],
      selected: []
    };
  },
  methods: {
    toggleAll() {
      if (this.selected.length) this.items = [];
      else this.selected = this.items.slice();
    }
  },
  watch: {
    activeTab: (oldValue, newValue) => {
      if (oldValue !== newValue) {
        this.selected = [];
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@1.5.14/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@1.5.14/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-tabs fixed-tabs v-model="activeTab">
      <v-tab v-for="tab in tabs" :key="tab">
        {{ tab }}
      </v-tab>
      <v-tab-item v-for="tab in tabs" :key="tab">
        <v-data-table v-model="selected" :headers="headers" :items="items" select-all item-key="name" class="elevation-1" hide-actions>
          <template v-slot:headers="props">
            <tr>
              <th>
                <v-checkbox :input-value="props.all" :indeterminate="props.indeterminate" primary hide-details @click.stop="toggleAll"></v-checkbox>
              </th>
              <th v-for="header in props.headers" :key="header.text">
                <v-icon small>arrow_upward</v-icon>
                {{ header.text }}
              </th>
            </tr>
          </template>
          <template v-slot:items="props">
            <tr :active="props.selected" @click="props.selected = !props.selected">
              <td>
                <v-checkbox :input-value="props.selected" primary hide-details></v-checkbox>
              </td>
              <td>{{ props.item.name }}</td>
              <td>{{ props.item.calories }}</td>
            </tr>
          </template>
        </v-data-table>
      </v-tab-item>
    </v-tabs>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

I am not quite sure how i will use that watch so if someone can help me with that, i sure would appreciate it. Thank you.

Comment: in a watch function, it's `newValue, oldValue`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using a fat arrow function for `activeTab`, it needs to be a normal function or it doesn't have a proper reference to `this`

Change to this:

```
activeTab: function (oldValue, newValue) { // function instead of =>
  if (oldValue !== newValue) {
    this.selected = [];
  }
}
```

Also, there's an issue with your code when you use the check all box.

As a good rule of thumb, all top level functions should be declared using `function`. Only use `=>` within the functions themselves when a nested function needs access to `this`

Comment: Thanks for that. I see. yeah i am not sure about the checkbox issue, i guess this was more to get an idea so that's not much of a worry.